# Why use a LengthFieldPrepender/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I thought about this for sometime now, why should I use a [LengthFieldPrepender](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html) and [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) in a TCP connection?

I don’t get the reason my only idea was to ensure that the data is transferred correctly and check the length but if my understanding of TCP is correct TCP itself should handle that the data is transferred correctly.

Comment: These parameters vary based on the custom protocol requirement. One such line -> **In most cases, the length field represents the length of the message body only, as shown in the previous examples. However, in some protocols, the length field represents the length of the whole message, including the message header**. Please go through your linked pages for better understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream protocol. It is up to the application to frame the data, i.e. determine where a unit of data - a packet or a message - starts and where it ends. The two basic methods to achieve this reliably are either to prepend the length of the message or to append a delimiter. There are many ways to encode the prepended length and there are many possibilities for a delimiter. The TCP protocol does **not** guarantee that the data that was sent by means of a single write will be received by a single read, although this is often the case for short messages.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the TCP protocol should handle that the data is transferred correctly.  Though in many cases, the amount of data being sent is not known at the time of reception (i.e. a variable amount).

To solve this, the length of the data being sent is added to the header of the packet.  If we know that the length is of a fixed size `n`, then we can read `n` bytes, then the next `length` bytes which holds the data.